# laravel Call to undefined function

Tags: laravel-5

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in
>   /home/karaweb/public_html/altius/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line
>   1943

From what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mbstring` php extension as mentioned in [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/call-to-undefined-function).

Check whether its installed or not by `echo phpinfo();` and look for `mbstring`